# Is there a publicly available database of all Apple products?

Tags: data-request

I'm looking for a database similar to [everymac](http://www.everymac.com) or [mactracker](http://www.mactracker.ca).

Comment: For a particular country, or for each country, or regardless of the country?

Comment: For all products throughout history, or just current ones?

Comment: Thanks, i'd be very happy just with the current ones but further goal is to have database of all products of all time. Regions and countries do not matter though.

Answer (score 2):

Apple provides this information in on their [Trademarks](https://www.apple.com/legal/intellectual-property/trademark/appletmlist.html) site, which includes all Apple product names and descriptions (an easy scrape off the page)

You reference [MacTracker](http://mactracker.ca/index.html), but that does provide what you need ([latest database](http://www.mactracker.ca/downloads/MacTracker_7.4.1.zip)). The terms are relatively [lenient for use](http://mactracker.ca/terms.html).